# how to disable right-click link with specific domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I want to disable right click link and i found this code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
           $('body').on('contextmenu', 'a', function(e){ return false; });
        }); 
    </script>
```

I want to add on a specific domain. something like this code (adfly fullpage script)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ad5fly_id = 4484512;
        var ad5fly_advert = 'int';
        var domains = ['depositfiles.com', 'rapidshare.com'];
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.adf.ly/js/link-converter.js"></script>
```

Basically, I dont want visitor to right click on my ad5fly link because they can bypass it easily. im talking about this: http://ad5f.ly/4484512/www.google.com : they can copy it and copy only the google link . then i wont earn any. help me guys. 
thanks !!

sorry for my bad english

Comment: You can disable right click but there are still ways around it, for example to disable Javascript in your browser or use Developer toolbar.

Comment: I see. But they can't open my blog unless they activate the js. btw thanks for the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you might be looking for

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).load(function(){
       $('body').on('contextmenu', 'a[href*=ad5f]', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            //or return false; does the same
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

If the anchor have a href which contains `ad5f` somewhere, then the contextmenu will be prevented.

**Update:**
I've added to be on `LOAD` instead of `READY` because if on ready, it might trigger before the `link-converter.js` ended doing it's thing (swapping urls) and the selector might fail.

Comment: thank youuuuuuuuu! very much. this is the code im looking for. THANK YOU, Maraming Salamat, Arigatou Gozaimasu!!

Comment: @IanOderon Do itashimashite. By the way, I've updated answer to add something that we need to prevent.

Comment: the load doesn't work in my situation. so i change it to ready and it start working again. hehe :)

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested this, but this is the solution from this thread here:

[Disabling right click on images using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753695/disabling-right-click-on-images-using-jquery)

```
$('body').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

If that doesn't work, you could also try attaching the function you `document` or `window` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the domains and cancel the right-click menu on page load.

```
  var domains = ['depositfiles.com', 'rapidshare.com'];
  for (var i = domains.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    $('body').on('contextmenu', 'a[href*="'+domains[i]+'"]', function(e){ return false });
  };
```