# JQuery: Click Class Reaction

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// ............. Your jQuery Code goes here .............

    //var myArray1 = new Array( "img1", "img2" , "img3",  "img4");
    var numImg = $('#thumbNail img').length; //number of images
    var num = 0;
    var curImg = 0;


    //Prevent Image Dragging
    $("img").bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
        return false;
    }); 



    //Prevent Right Click on Mouse
    $("img").bind("mousedown", function(e){
        return false;
    });



    $(".leftThumbNail").live("click", function(){ 
        alert("HY"); 
    });


});
```

I am trying to have it react to when ever I click on images inside class "leftThumbnail". This class contains 2 images on the left panel. Whenever I click any of the images from that class, nothing seems to happen.

I also tried:

```
$(".leftThumbNail").click(function() {

        alert("HEY");

    });
```

In my "leftThumbNail" class I have the following:

```
<div class="leftThumbNail">   

<img id = "img1" src="img/thumb/image1.jpg" class = "image1Position" alt="Image 1">

<img id = "img2" src="img/thumb/image2.jpg" class = "image2Position" alt="Image 2" >

</div>
```

Comment: `$("img").bind("mousedown", function(e){` prevents all click events on said elements since a click event is comprised of a mousedown AND a mouseup event.

Comment: what version of jQuery are u using? 1.4? try using `.on()`.

Comment: I am trying to prevent only right click and the question here suggests thats (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753695/disabling-right-click-on-images-using-jquery)

Comment: That's great, but it does much more than just prevent right click.

Comment: i am required to use 1.10.2

Comment: is there a way JUST to prevent right click?

Comment: `.live()` was removed in 1.9.

Comment: `$(".leftThumbNail").live` won't work in 1.10.2

Comment: Read the answers in the question you just linked to.

Comment: the only answer that suggests binding a `mousedown` handler says that you need to check `event.which` to see which button was used, so you don't also block the left button.

Comment: You can't prevent someone from downloading images from your webpage. For the user to view the image, they would have already had to download it (it's in their temporary internet files folder). Just remove the attempts to prevent that and your code might start working, assuming there are no other errors.

Comment: @KevinB +1 not only that, if it's on the screen, it can be screen captured.

Comment: You could use flash to make it harder, but again that doesn't stop screen capturing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok try this:

```
$('img').on({
    contextmenu:function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    },
    click:function(e){
        if(e.which === 3){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    },
    dragstart:function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}); 

$(".leftThumbNail").on('click', function(){ 
    alert('HY'); 
});
```

This does the following:

- Kills right-click by checking `e.which` to be specific to right-clicks
- updates to `.on()`, the modern version of what you wanted to do
- Combines your handlers for `'img'` into a single `.on()` declaration

To consolidate it even more:

```
$('img').on({
    contextmenu:function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    },
    click:function(e){
        if(e.which === 3){
            e.preventDefault();
        } else if($(this).hasClass('leftThumbNail')){
            alert('HY');
        }
    },
    dragstart:function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

No more extra handlers ... all handled in one now!

**EDIT** Modified to include prevention dragging (performed by using `dragstart` handler). Also changed `return false` to the more proper `e.preventDefault()` to allow for bubbling.

Comment: for some reasons, now my images are able to be dragged; so it answered the problem of right clicking and reaction to class clicking but re-introduced the problem of picture dragging

Comment: @user1234440 added in prevention of `dragstart` events, which should cure dragging as well.