# Disabling right click in CkEditor 4.3

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Is there a way to programmatically disable the right click of the mouse on a particular element inside the editor?

I need this to use this functionality to disable the resizing of one particular table element inside the editor, which is managed by the *tabletools* plug-in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most correct solution would be to disable proper command when such table is selected, but  I see that unfortunately it doesn't disable menu item for that command, but only prevents executing that command. So less cool solution has to be used:

```
editor.on( 'contentDom', function() {
    editor.editable().attachListener( editor.editable(), 'contextmenu', function( evt ) {
        console.log( evt.data.getTarget() );
        evt.stop();
        evt.data.preventDefault();
    }, null, null, 0 );
} );
```

This will disable context menu completely. You can add proper condition based on `evt.data.getTarget()`.

Comment: This is not CKEditor - browser displays those resize handlers. You can disable them by [`enableObjectResizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Rich-Text_Editing_in_Mozilla) command.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable right-click on particular elements using jQuery as:

```
$('img').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
    return false;
});
```

Refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753695/disabling-right-click-on-images-using-jquery) for more details.

Comment: Yes, it's true. But this method doesn't work in CkEditor