# Disable rightclick on on images

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently using this script to prevent right click on one of my site. I have tried different tweaks on the code because I would like it to prevent right click ONLY on images (right click it's everywhere).

Any idea?

Thanks in advance for your help

```js
//Disable right mouse click Script

var message = "Stop trying stealing pics! :P";

///////////////////////////////////
function clickIE4() {
  if (event.button == 2) {
    alert(message);
    return false;
  }
}

function clickNS4(e) {
  if (document.layers || document.getElementById && !document.all) {
    if (e.which == 2 || e.which == 3) {
      alert(message);
      return false;
    }
  }
}

if (document.layers) {
  document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
  document.onmousedown = clickNS4;
} else if (document.all && !document.getElementById) {
  document.onmousedown = clickIE4;
}

document.oncontextmenu = new Function("alert(message);return false")
```

Comment: The NS4 and document.layers marks this as a script from previous millennium. You do know that the images are just a "save as web page" away to be saved on the hard disk?

Comment: Your solution may be here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753695/disabling-right-click-on-images-using-jquery

Comment: Also click and hold, drag to new tab will open the image for saving

Comment: Don't even waste your time doing this. There are lots of ways of saving an image in the DOM without right clicking it, so this solves nothing. All it does is annoy your users. If you don't want people to steal content, don't put it online.

Comment: Or add a watermark

Comment: Please don't automatically assume it's to prevent saving an image. If you need a why, imagine three good answers and then proceed. ;-)

Comment: @HerbertVan-Vliet I was not assuming: `var message = "Stop trying stealing pics! :P";`

Comment: Ah yes, my bad.

Answer (score 6):

Use `contextmenu` event:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("img").on("contextmenu",function(){
        return false;
     }); 
 });
```

```css
img{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded">
```

Comment: Click and hold, drag to new tab

Comment: @mplungjan: I know this, and it's not helpful. I'm not trying to prevent saving an image offline.

Comment: @HerbertVan-Vliet Hva da?