# Which web browsers disallow the disabling of the right-click context menu?

Tags: javascript, browser, save, contextmenu, disable

When on a web page, we can right-click on an image which brings up a pop-up context menu that includes options like `Save As` and more. This menu apparently can be [disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753695/disabling-right-click-on-images-using-jquery) with a Javascript script so that it doesn't pop up when an image is right-clicked. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page) answer says that

> many browsers have a security option to disallow disabling of the
> right click (context) menu anyway.

Which browsers exactly disallow the disabling of the context menu? Chrome, Firefox, Bravo, Opera, Tor, Edge, ...?

Comment: That answer is from 12 years ago and as far as I know, no browser disallows the ability to prevent a right-click on an element. Having said that, trying to prevent this is futile. It doesn't stop anyone from doing any of the things on the context menu if they really want to and preventing native behavior is generally considered a bad practice. I would encourage you to read the comments left for the question you linked to.

Comment: In FF's about:config there seems to be `dom.event.contextmenu.enabled` option (true by default), so at least in FF you can disable `oncontextmenu` event.