# How to hide some property in Right click using JS

Tags: javascript, html

I my web application I want to Hide/ Remove some for the menus like View Source, Properties using JavaScript coding. This should available in entire webpage.

Comment: I don't want to hide complete right click menu, I just want to hide some of the property

Answer (score 1):

**Do not do it.**

You only make your users angry but you can not stop them any way.

See also [How do I disable right click on my web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page)

If I can't stop you from doing it. You can only disable the whole menu:

```
<script language="javascript">
document.onmousedown=disableclick;
Function disableclick(e)
{
  if(event.button==2)
   {
     return false;    
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var message="Sorry, right-click has been disabled"; 

function clickIE() {if (document.all) {(message);return false;}} 
function clickNS(e) {
   if(document.layers||(document.getElementById&&!document.all)) { 
       if (e.which==2||e.which==3) {(message);return false;}}} 
       if (document.layers){
          document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
          document.onmousedown=clickNS;
       } 
       else{
          document.onmouseup=clickNS;
          document.oncontextmenu=clickIE;
       } 
document.oncontextmenu=new Function("return false")
```

This is code disable the right click.