# How can I remove "View this image" link when I right click on a image with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousedown

I have an image.
When I left click on it, it should increase the value behind the image by 1.
When I right click on it, it should decrease the value behind the image by 2.

The problem is, when I right click the image, it decreases the value correctly. However, Mozilla Firefox pops a window like "Copy this image, View this image" etc.

How can I prevent this?

Comment: search a bit; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the context menu, a standard feature of Modern OS' and not specific to Firefox.

To disable the context menu for images, use:

```
$(document).on('contextmenu', 'img', function() { return false; });
```

via [DevGrow](http://devgrow.com/quick-tip-preventing-right-click-context-menu-with-jquery/), modified to use the jQuery 1.7+ .on() to attach the event handler.