# How to disable mouse right click and ctrl+v & ctrl+c keypress using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I disable right click on my web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page)

I want to disable right click  and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> keypresses on a web page using JavaScript. I have a page where customers has to enter the enquiry details. I don't want them to copy some data and paste it in some fields. Anyone, please help me.

Comment: Why, in god's name, why?! Will you also disable the Edit menu or any other possible method how something can be pasted?

Comment: Oh, and if it's e.g. for a "repeat your email" field: EXTREMELY ANNOYING. I use autocompletion for the first one so copy&paste is perfectly safe! Stop restricting your users in annoying ways. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to prevent copy-pasting the data? If you force people to retype the same thing, they're just more prone to make typos or leave something out. The copy-paste is also for *your* benefit.

Comment: `$(document).bind('copy', function(e) {
        alert('Copy is not allowed !!!');
        e.preventDefault();
    }); 
    $(document).bind('paste', function() {
        alert('Paste is not allowed !!!');
        e.preventDefault();
    }); 
    $(document).bind('cut', function() {
        alert('Cut  is not allowed !!!');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $(document).bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
        alert('Right Click  is not allowed !!!');
        e.preventDefault();
    });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

Check this link [Disabling-the-right-click-on-web-page](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11222/Disabling-the-right-click-on-web-page)

```
<script language="javascript">
document.onmousedown=disableclick;
status="Right Click Disabled";
Function disableclick(e)
{
  if(event.button==2)
   {
     alert(status);
     return false;  
   }
}
</script>
```