# How to serve an image without possibility of easy saving it from browser?

Tags: php, javascript, apache

I want to show a set of images only on my website. 
I want to avoid end-user posibility of easy saving. 
I know that user can save an image with print screen, but this is not a easy way because require some work after that.

Comment: Lookup 'Shrinkwrapping', it's a technique where you place a transparent gif over the image you want to protect. This stops the ability for in browser right click->save. Obviously anyone in the know can get still get the image but this will stop most non-techie users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to draw an image to a canvas element, thus stopping a user from saving the image using a DOM inspector or right-click menu. This technique wont work on older browsers though.

Answer (score 1):

1. display in an applet (e.g flash, java)
2. use server-side operations to chop the image up into random-sized squares/rectangles and use a client-side table to display the parts in "assembled" format
3. use CSS overlays so that right-clicking on the image gets you the overlay instead of the image
4. give up because if someone wants to steal your image, they will.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to prevent them 100% from doing it, but you can make it harder.

You can have a .htaccess rule which doesn't allow direct access to it (must be loaded from one of your site's webpages)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Then you can prevent right clicking on your website so they can't just click copy image. See:
[How do I disable right click on my web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page)

Note there is no good solution.

Comment: Instead of disableing right click I can use an transparent layer over.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

- split it into multiple pieces (require some changes on the HTML code too)
- apply as a css `background-image` on a fully transparent gif / png *
- apply a watermark with [gd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) (in php)
- or mix these

But the user can still *save* it with a simple print-screen, as you wrote.

(*) f.ex:

```
<img src="blank.gif" style="width: 200px; height: 100px; background-image: url('image.jpg');" />
```