# Right Click Disable in PHP

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I am using an application in which ppt slides and and videos are used.
I want to disable right click in all the browser, is it possible to do so?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page

Comment: It is possible yes with javascript but totally defeated with view source

Comment: Why would you want to do that. It's nothing but annoying for your users. It will not protect your files from being accessible.

Comment: @NathanQ: some confidential matters are to be displayed that sy need to diable

Comment: @GBD: may be. i didnt knw dat bfre

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, PHP in server side, right click is client side.

you can achieve it by using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{ 
       $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e){
              return false;
       }); 
})
```

Comment: thanks you save my life dear.

Comment: between what tags to put this text ?

Comment: @Web.11 inside a script tag

Answer (score 1):

Right click is a feature of your browser. YOu can't disable it through PHP (PHP generates HTML).

In Javascript it's possible:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```

Answer (score 1):

**Dont do that**

No matter what you do, you can't prevent users from having full access to every bit of data on your website. Any Javascript you code can be rendered moot by simply turning off Javascript on the browser (or using a plugin like NoScript). Additionally, there's no way to disable the ability of any user to simply "view source" or "view page info" (or use wget) for your site.

It's not worth the effort. It won't actually work. It will make your site actively hostile to users. They will notice this and stop visiting. There is no benefit to doing this, only wasted effort and lost traffic.

Comment: I totally disagree with you. I believe who ever wants to achieve this has a valid reason. Take for instant i want to set a form value to disabled=True. Any developer with basic knowledge on forms can enable the form and set preferred value or even inject sqli. Maybe he needs this and does not need to set it on all pages.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(this).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}); 
</script>
<script type="text/JavaScript"> 
    function killCopy(e){ return false } 
    function reEnable(){ return true } 
    document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false"); 
    if (window.sidebar)
    { 
        document.onmousedown=killCopy; 
        document.onclick=reEnable; 
    } 
</script>
```

//By using above code you right click will be disabled as well as no one can copy your page content

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
To disable right click in all the browser using javascript.

```
<script language="javascript">
           var message="This function is not allowed here.";
           function clickIE4(){
                 if (event.button==2){
                     alert(message);
                     return false;
                 }
           }
           function clickNS4(e){
                if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){
                        if (e.which==2||e.which==3){
                                  alert(message);
                                  return false;
                        }
                }
           }
           if (document.layers){
                 document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
                 document.onmousedown=clickNS4;
           }
           else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){
                 document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
           }
           document.oncontextmenu=new Function("alert(message);return false;")
</script>
```