# input field for my website search form does not accept input

Tags: javascript, html, css

My website is http://1stbirthdaypartytheme.com/
The input field for my website search form does not accept input in FireFox 17.01. 
The search works correctly in Chrome and in I.E.
In other words if you open my website in Firefox, there is a search field in the top right hand corner of the header, just below my social contact buttons.
If you place the cursor into the input box and type nothing happens.
When you click on the magnifying glass you're returned to the homepage.
How can I, or what do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Dear Michael G. Schurmann, please accept *pete's* answer as the correct one. He has put effort in solving it, and this is a way of thanking him.

Answer (score 2):

When I overwrote this bit in the DOM Inspector, it started working in Firefox:

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript"> 
<!-- 
function disableselect(e){
    return false
} 
function reEnable(){
    return true
} 
document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false") 
if (window.sidebar){
    document.onmousedown=disableselect
    document.onclick=reEnable
}
// -->
</SCRIPT>
```

That said, disabling the "right-click" on your webpage just made debugging this a little more difficult. Don't disable "right-click", there's no point in doing so:

[How do I disable right click on my web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page)

http://www.sitepoint.com/dont-disable-right-click/

Comment: hello, thank you for your help, this fixed my problems, I am grateful for your help and time. MGS

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of validation errors for this page. I assume some of them are causing this field to malfunction. Please run your code through [this validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) and eliminate the errors.