# Drag and drop text into textarea

Tags: jquery, jsp

In one textarea I am able to drag and drop text into it but in another the text is rejected. I'm using Chrome and thought it would be the browser allowing drag and drop of text. But after some googling I see that there is javascript code to enable it. I can't find any good resources to confirm this though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a webpage, you can drag/drop text from/to it. There exists a JavaScript code which disables this, or disable copying Images, or right-clicking the mouse. There are many of this kind.

You may find more information on: [here](http://www.boogiejack.com/no_copy_paste.html) or in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page), depends on the script you're looking for. But generally - I wouldn't recommend you to actually use it (except for experience).

Comment: So a textarea by default should accept the text being dragged in?

Comment: "I wouldn't recommend you to actually use it" - why is that? is it still true with HTML5?

Answer (score 0):

Put the text into an inline-block element (div) after selection with JavaScript. The drag and drop event will take the container div not the text, which you'll be able to handle.

Comment: The text can be dragged in from outside the browser. This is not handled by default?