# How to protect the url from being copy and pasted

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hey guys do you know how I can implement this in Rails?

Lets say I hyperlink the word "Go here" with "www.example.com".

how can I protect the link so that nobody see and copy and paste and reuse the url I am using for "Go here".

I trying to make a link for business coupons and trying to make sure not anybody can copy and paste the url and use it.

Comment: FWIW, you can make it more difficult to find a URL, but there's no way you can obfuscate/hide it entirely.

Comment: There's clearly a way to disable right-click (see http://www.shoutmeloud.com/copy-from-right-click-disabled-websites.html).  I'm not sure how you do it - maybe the WP plugin that's referenced there will give you some ideas.  As @zeantsoi said, there's no good way to fully remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You could try disabling right click, but that would just be annoying for your users.

Here's a way to do it: [How do I disable right click on my web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page)