# How can we make Image non-downloadable which is opened with fancybox?

Tags: javascript, image, download, fancybox, right-click

I have searched about making image non downloadable, but I didn't get any reasonable answer. So can we make image non-downloadable which is opened with FanyBox? I am making an app where I don't want people to download image. I have few gallery's which open with FancyBox. Making right-click disable simply make user annoyed. I want to make right-click disable only on FanyBox.

Comment: Hi, you can't make an image non downloadable if you want to display it somewhere in your webapplication! You can restrict the direct access by url if the user is logged in.

Comment: Restriction means i am hiding those images for other user. But i don't want to do that. If it could be possible that without making image restriction we could make image non downloadable. May be by putting them inside iframe or some container. Still searching.

Comment: Not really no, by definition the browser has to download the image to be able to display it. I would look at adding a watermark to your images. There are JS scripts that will disable copy & paste/right click but anyone with rudimentary knowledge will found a way around it

Comment: In worst case the user can simply make a screenshot.

Comment: I know that can be done. But if user is newbie to these tricks. we could make images private to some extent. I know We can't stop screenshot. But before that we could make some restriction.

Comment: For example prevent the right click: [prevent the right click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page)

Comment: Right.Disabling  Right click is simply annoying user. But i want to disable right click on fancybox only. when it open image in fencybox

Comment: Check http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#useful No.3 (disable right click for fancybox only)