# Disable Right-Clicking In HTML5 Video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm using an HTML5 video player on my website and I want to disable right-clicking on all my videos.

I tried using this code and it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#videoElementID').bind('contextmenu',function() { return false; });
});
</script>
```

I'm using WordPress and placed the function above in the `header.php` file.

How can I check what is the `#videoElementID` name for my player? I tried with all the DIV elements on the page and it still doesn't work. I know this won't prevent users to download my videos but I really need to make this work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I disable right click on my web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page)

Comment: Is the video player being loaded dynamically into the DOM?

Answer (score 63):

My favorite method which is quick and easy and does not require javascript is to add the `oncontextmenu="return false;"` to the video tag.

So something like this:

```
<video oncontextmenu="return false;" id="my-video-player" width="854" height="480" controls autoplay>
  <source src="https://example.com/link-to-my-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

You can also trigger it programatically such as:

```
document.querySelector('video').setAttribute('oncontextmenu', "return false;")
```

Comment: I just found that you can circumvent this by right clicking, holding the mouse button, moving the mouse slightly then releasing... somehow it then still opens the context menu!?

Comment: Note this _does_ require JavaScript! The `return false;` is JavaScript. If you disable JavaScript, the context menu appears as normal.

Answer (score 20):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $("video").bind("contextmenu",function(){
        return false;
        });
 } );
```

This should disable right click on all the video elements in that page. Hope this helps.

Comment: I just tried and it still doesn't work. I tested with both Firefox and Chrome. Any ideas?

Comment: @user3517251 - is it happening only for **video** element, or all other elements. i mean, did this also not work `$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(){
        return false;
        });`

Comment: this doesn't work either. it has no effect. perhaps something blocks it. any ideas what it could be?

Comment: I managed to get it to work by adding the following values in the DIV element of the Video. <div oncontextmenu="return false" onselectstart="return false" ondragstart="return false">here's the video embedcode</div> . It works great in Firefox, Chrome and IE.

Comment: ideally it should have worked ... a check you can do is whether jquery.js file was loaded or not. You can do it by placing- `alert("jquery loaded")` inside your `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Answer (score 5):

**For React use =>**

```
onContextMenu={e => e.preventDefault()}

<video onContextMenu={e => e.preventDefault()}>
  <source src={`your_video_url`} type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

Answer (score 4):

I was recently trying to disable right click for video element. This code worked for me.

```
 document.querySelector("video").addEventListener("contextmenu", (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: I would change it to querySelectorAll with a forEach in case you have multiple videos on a page.

Answer (score 1):

The right click menu is a function of the web browser. To disable it, you can try to add the following JavaScript to the head section of your web page, just before the  tag.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('video').bind('contextmenu',function() { return false; });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It works fine for me.

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(ev){
    if(ev.target.nodeName=='VIDEO')
    {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Better to use `onContextMenu={(e) => e.preventDefault()}` under the video tag of HTML5.

Comment: Could you add an explanation to the answer? Why is it better? Better then what?