# Disable Right Click on Video

Tags: javascript

I've just loaded video.js plugin on my **wordpress** site.

I would like to find out if it is possible to disable the links 'get video url' etc. I want to add videos from youtube but don't want users linking to the unlisted videos. The videos are for a course and I don't want them shared. only users on the course get access to the videos.

But, the YOUTUBE logo still needs to be active due to their terms and conditions.

Many thanks

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with WordPress.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992645/disable-right-clicking-in-html5-video

Comment: Can also be duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page . Check verified answer and come up with a solution binding this only to your video. Being that said, there's always a way around to get your video url easily.