# Right click being disabled on AUDIO

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio, html5-audio

I have seen a method to disable right click, but I was wondering how do you disable it on HTML5 audio.

I have seen examples for disabling right click using a line of JS, but however it does not work on DOM.

JS:

```js
document.addEventListener('contextaudio', event => event.preventDefault());
```

HTML:

```
   <audio controls controlslist="nodownload" name="media">
      <source
        src="test.mp3"
        type="audio/mp3"
      />
    </audio>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Right-Clicking In HTML5 Video?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22992645/disable-right-clicking-in-html5-video)

Comment: No, I actually view that question before this one and the other question was not helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply add `oncontextmenu= "return false;"` like this:

```html
<audio oncontextmenu="return false;" controls controlslist="nodownload" name="media">
      <source src="cool.mp3" type="audio/mp3"/>
</audio>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! That code was right and worked on my website.

Comment: You're welcome! When the answer works, mark it as correct answer.