# How to I stop right mouse click on my website

Tags: html, youtube

i would like to disable a user from right mouse clicking on an embedded youtube video.

How to I do this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I disable right click on my web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page)

Comment: Why do you what that?

Answer (score 0):

### 1st Way:

We can set the oncontextmenu="return false" in the tags of the HTML page where you have embedded youtube video

so HTML part will probably look like

```
<{tagname} oncontextmenu="return false">
...
</{tagname}>
```

### 2nd Way:

In this way we add a JavaScript method, in this we check if click is right click or left click if it is right click then a message is displayed like "Right click disabled".


Set an id where you have added code for embedded youtube video. Add this Script in the HTML Document for that id.

```
<script language="javascript">
document.getElementByID({idname}).onmousedown=disableclick;
status="Right Click Disabled";
Function disableclick(e)
{
  if(event.button==2)
   {
     alert(status);
     return false;  
   }
}
</script>
```

Note: In this solution if you click the right click it displays the message:

`“Right click disabled”`

If we want to remove the message box then this solution do not work.


`*Replace {...} with appropriate names.`


Reference: [Click here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11222/Disabling-the-right-click-on-web-page)