# disable right click in shiny app

Tags: shiny-server, shiny

I would like to disable right click on a shiny app. There is information I would like to not have copied and pasted elsewhere. I understand, a snapshot of the page will remain a possibility, but that's ok. Is there a way to use javascript to disable this functionality in a shiny app? I tried the following, but got an error.

```
tags$head(HTML("<script type='text/javascript'>document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
}, false)</script>")),
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a JavaScript, not a Shiny, question. [Here's the first SO response to this question that I found on Google](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page). Basically, there are many ways for users around it, and it's not recommended to do it because it's mostly just annoying to the user, but you *can* do it.

Comment: I understand that. I am having trouble implementing document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
}, false); in the shiny app

Answer (score 0):

You can set a right-click disable to a block of code with its id and run it with shinyjs

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

jscode <- "
shinyjs.init = function() {
    document.getElementById('plot').addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
    document.getElementById('myarea').addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
}"

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jscode, functions = c()),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel("Plot", plotOutput("plot")),
    tabPanel("Summary", verbatimTextOutput("summary")),
    tabPanel("Table", tableOutput("table"),div(id="myarea", h1("You can't right click me")))
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
    output$plot <- renderPlot({ 
      plot(cars)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```