# Disable Context Menu (Right click) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, contextmenu, right-click

I want to disable the right click menu on a table. Because I'm using the rightclick to change the color of it (did a little Battleship game). However I did not found anything that still works. So I would really appreciate your answer :)

This is the call:

```
<td class="tdBox" onclick="attack(this, ${xStatus.count}, ${yStatus.count})" onmouseover="background(this)" onmouseout="backgroundLeave(this)" oncontextmenu="markField(this)">
```

and this is the JavaScript function:

```
function markField(obj) {
    obj.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    //return false;
}
```

Comment: looks like a partial dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page

Comment: Take the code from the link kay27 posted. In that replace `alert(status);` line by your colour change code. 
P.S. I would suggest to not use right click for your input however, as that is never a good idea on a web app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to override the `contextmenu` event handler:

```
document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  alert('Right click');

  // Or, in you case: markField()
});
```

Note: using `document` is not a requirement. It will work on any DOM node. Alternatively, you can make the blockage conditional by checking the target of `e`.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/h1jdr1ew/1/

Comment: This does work partly since I dont want to disable the rightclick on the whole site. However I found a solution based on this by using getElementsByClassName.

`function disableRightClick(){
 var tdBox = document.getElementsByClassName("tdBox");
 for (i = 0; i < tdBox.length; i++) {
     tdBox[i].addEventListener("contextmenu", function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     
   });
 }
}`

Comment: Yes, it will work on any DOM node, not just `document`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<script language="javascript">
function markField(obj)
{
  if(event.button==2)
   {
     //add your code here
     obj.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
     return false;    
   }
}
</script>

<td class="tdBox" onclick="attack(this, ${xStatus.count}, ${yStatus.count})" 
onmouseover="background(this)" onmouseout="backgroundLeave(this)" 
oncontextmenu="markField(this)">
```

Comment: I have tried it with return false; but it did not work.

Comment: what is the error coming? Also, which browser? Some browser do not allow disabling right click.

Edit: Check in console to see if JS throws an error.