# how to disable right click on popup window when open window.open

Tags: javascript

My code is:

```
var openpopup = window.open(hostName1, "Report", "_blank", params);
openpopup.oncontextmenu = false;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable right click on my web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page)

Answer (score 0):

Change your JavaScript to :

```
var openpopup = window.open(hostname,"Report", "_blank", params);
    openpopup.oncontextmenu = function() {
    return false;
}
```

`oncontextmenu()` is a function not an variable. So you have to assign function to which will return `false` for disabling right click.