# How to disable download option for html5 video player in UC browser (Android)

Tags: javascript, android, html, video, uc-browser

We are trying to protect our video data from being downloaded.
As of regular practice i am trying to disable contextmenu/longclick/rightclick, But it is not helpful.
Below is the sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
video{
        height : 100%;
        width : 100%;
}
</style>
<body>

<video>
  <source src="http://184.72.239.149/vod/smil:BigBuckBunny.smil/playlist.m3u8" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>


</body>
<script>
$('video').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
    return false;
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: If people want it, they usually find a way to get the videos anyway. Other than that, [this might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page).