# How to hide view source code of website & disable right click mouse?

Tags: javascript, xcode, html

The following website has disable right click and Ctrl+ button.

http://www.travelonlines.com/

Can anyone shine some light on how this is possible?

Comment: Note that you can never fully hide the source code; view-source:http://www.travelonlines.com/

Comment: [take a look at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page) There are ways to prevent. But there are also enough examples of how to get it anyway..