# How to restrict default context menu on long press in android/ios devices and show custom menu?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to restrict default context menu on long press in android/ios devices and show my custom menu. 
Please note that it's a normal web page opening in a mobile browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the same as [disabling right click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page) - add this listener:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```

*Tested on Firefox for Android*

Comment: @Sairam Rugada Did it help?

Comment: It worked fine. Sorry for the late response as I missed it.