# Javascript events in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, events

I noticed that these function doesn't work good in Firefox, but does in Chrome.

I use these function in a game in Js to shoot bullet (left mouse click) and to create a fireball all around the player with the right click that burns everyone in a small radius.

```
document.onclick = function(event) {

    if(!player){    //to avoid onclick to be used before calling Player();
        return;
    }

    if(player.canAttack && player.distance >= 80) {     //not for sword attack
        performAttack(player);
        player.canAttack = false;
    }

    if(player.distance < 80)
        performAttack(player);

    //event.preventDefault();
}

document.oncontextmenu = function(event) {

    //hide default behaviour of right click -> no context menu popup
    event.preventDefault();

    if(player.obtainedGadjet > 0) {
        player.pressingMouseRight = true;
        performSpecialAttack(player);
    }

}
```

In the `performAttack` function I set `player.isStopped = true`, so my `updatePlayer()` doesn't change `player.x` and `player.y` while he's attacking. The same for the fireball attack. I want my player stays there.

It works in chrome, my player stops, attacks,and then can moves again, but in Firefox if I right click it somethimes acts instead as I have left clicked, so shoot the magic ball, and maybe then the fireball too. Furthermore, my player ignore `isStopped = true`, it seems like in Firefox `oncontextmenu` has "lower priority" than other events.

Any idea? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please note that a [`click` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) contains information about which button was pressed. You can [try yourself with something like](http://jsbin.com/cokepopote/edit?js,console,output):

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
  console.log(ev.button);
});
```

And, yes, `click` events are fired when you right-click, even if you're doing something on related `contextmenu` events.

So your code should look a bit more like

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(ev){
  if (ev.button === 0) {
    // Perform primary action
  } else if (ev.button === 2) {
    // Perform secondary action
  }
});

document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(ev){
  ev.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, now with your solution works with Firefox but no more with Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Using the same click event is advisable as said by Ivan. You may also want to [read this other discussion here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page) about best practices and why it's not always good to disable default right click behaviour (i.e.: it's not always guaranteed to work).