# How the "View Page Source" option was hidden from the mouse right click option?

Tags: javascript, html, web, right-click

[image: No "View Page Source" option, rather it is showing "View Selection Source"]

How a developer can hide the "View Page Source" option from right click menu like this? I got right click menu options but no "View Page Source" option in the full website. How to do it?

Comment: its pointless, it does noting, any one can get around it. just accept anything sent to the browser is viewable

Comment: This will be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page

Comment: It's called a "custom context menu". Using Javascript you can create your own right click context menu. But as @smith said, it's pointless. The browser cannot display a website without receiving the source code and therefor a user can _always_ get their hands on the source one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

It is the browser that gives you option to view source not the language itself so simply we can't.

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false;">
```