# How do I disable image hotlinking from a webpage?

Tags: wordpress

Is there a WordPress plugin or a `.htaccess` mod which disables right click on an image ?- like how it is on this site https://brooksconstruction.com.au/two-storey-homes-perth/

This pic helps understand the question better.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable right click on my web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page)

Comment: Not really. Having right click is fine. But I do not want the "save image" options.

Comment: Disabling right click doesn't prevent people from stealing your content.  There are other ways to download site content like using `wget`.  All it does is ruin UX by inhibiting a native browser feature.  You can prevent hotlinking with proper htaccess rules though.