# disable mouse middle click and right click on links wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I want to disable mouse middle click and right click on links. Via Javascript or PHP.

Or, change the action of middle and right click to act as a simple left click

Is that even possible?

I tried some codes I've found over the internet. like this one:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
document.oncontextmenu=new Function('return false');
document.onmousedown=mainfn;
document.onclick=mainfn;
function mainfn(e){
    e=(!e) ?window.event :e;
        try{
        if (e) {
               e.returnValue = false;
                e.cancelBubble = true;
                if (e.stopPropagation) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                }
                if (e.preventDefault) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        } catch (c) {alert(c); }

}
```

This should disable all mouse events. but still middle on links, works.

Comment: It is possible and must happen in Javascript.  Please note, preventing these clicks will not make your website any more secure. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page

Comment: `<a oncontextmenu="return false;" href="` seems to work just fine in Chrome.  Seems that middle click may not be reliable.