# Protect Templates Against Stealers (a.k.a. HTTRack)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

So recently I did buy a few templates for my business. They are HTML/CSS/JQUERY/JS/PHP based.

The problem is the following: In my field, the concurrence in pretty high and it's very common for people to download the templates and use them on their own. And since I did pay a lot for them, I don't want someone to get them for free, so I'm looking for a solution.

Here are a few things I thought about:

- Upload the libraries (CSS style files/JS ones) to a CDN and the access will be given only to my website URL.
- Making some function in PHP that links it to the CTA button. So if the PHP function doesn't exists, the CTA button will be dead.

I have some little experience when it comes about web dev. so I'm not even sure if these solutions are doable. That's why I'm asking you, maybe some of you know better.

Thank you very much and have a great day!

Comment: No, what you want is not really possible.

Comment: _“and the access will be given only to my website URL”_ - your website URL is not making these requests - my browser is. And even if you implemented a referrer check or something like that - as soon as I visit your site “normally”, as any other regular visitor would, my browser would allow me to inspect and save all those external resources anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The protection mechanisms can be different depending on the level of security you want to achieve. For example, even if you block attempts to copy your templates by using software like HTTRack (which is pretty easy), someone could do it manually anyway. The best practice is to utilize multiple protection mechanisms at the same time. None of them will prevent content replication by themselves, but when combined, they will at least **lower** the probability of someone doing it. As said in the comments, it's impossible to completely prevent someone from stealing these templates.

1. [DCMA](https://www.dmca.com/) can help you with taking down websites that contain your
   stolen content
2. [Distil](https://www.distilnetworks.com/web-scraping/) is pretty good at protecting against web scraping, check
   it out
3. You could add watermarks to the images that you use
4. [Obfuscate](https://jscrambler.com/products/code-integrity/javascript-obfuscation?gclid=CjwKCAjwxt_tBRAXEiwAENY8hZrOT08NYgZnv2_mu8Pnshx9ZYYXhN7tzyCSrpt3n1njh7TQoerJyxoCpC4QAvD_BwE) all JavaScript code to make it harder to modify
5. [Disable RMB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page) on your website
6. Create a `.htaccess` file in your server's root directory with the following content:

   ```
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} almaden [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Anarchie [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ASPSeek [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^attach [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^autoemailspider [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BackWeb [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bandit [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BatchFTP [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^BlackWidow [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Bot\ mailto:craftbot@yahoo.com [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Buddy [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^bumblebee [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^CherryPicker [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ChinaClaw [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^CICC [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Collector [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Copier [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Crescent [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Custo [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DA [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DIIbot [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DISCo\ Pump [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Demon [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Download\ Wonder [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Downloader [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Drip [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^DSurf15a [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^eCatch [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EasyDL/2.99 [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EirGrabber [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} email [NC,OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailCollector [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailSiphon [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EmailWolf [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Express\ WebPictures [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ExtractorPro [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^EyeNetIE [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FileHound [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^FlashGet [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} FrontPage [NC,OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetRight [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetSmart [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GetWeb! [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^gigabaz [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go\!Zilla [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go!Zilla [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Go-Ahead-Got-It [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^gotit [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Grabber [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^GrabNet [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Grafula [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^grub-client [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HMView [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^HTTrack [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^httpdown [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*httrack.* [NC,OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ia_archiver [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Stripper [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Image\ Sucker [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Indy*Library [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Indy\ Library [NC,OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InterGET [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InternetLinkagent [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Internet\ Ninja [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^InternetSeer.com [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Iria [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JBH*agent [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JetCar [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JOC\ Web\ Spider [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^JustView [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^larbin [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LeechFTP [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LexiBot [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^lftp [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Link*Sleuth [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^likse [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Link [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^LinkWalker [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mag-Net [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Magnet [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mass\ Downloader [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Memo [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Microsoft.URL [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MIDown\ tool [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mirror [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mister\ PiX [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla.*Indy [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla.*NEWT [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Mozilla*MSIECrawler [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MS\ FrontPage* [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MSFrontPage [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MSIECrawler [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^MSProxy [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Navroad [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NearSite [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetAnts [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetMechanic [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetSpider [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Net\ Vampire [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NetZIP [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^NICErsPRO [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Ninja [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Octopus [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Explorer [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Offline\ Navigator [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Openfind [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PageGrabber [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Papa\ Foto [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pavuk [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^pcBrowser [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Ping [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^PingALink [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Pockey [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^psbot [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Pump [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^QRVA [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^RealDownload [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Reaper [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Recorder [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^ReGet [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Scooter [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Seeker [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Siphon [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^sitecheck.internetseer.com [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SiteSnagger [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SlySearch [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SmartDownload [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Snake [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SpaceBison [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^sproose [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Stripper [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Sucker [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperBot [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^SuperHTTP [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Surfbot [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Szukacz [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^tAkeOut [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Teleport\ Pro [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^URLSpiderPro [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Vacuum [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^VoidEYE [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Image\ Collector [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Sucker [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebAuto [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^[Ww]eb[Bb]andit [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^webcollage [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebCopier [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Web\ Downloader [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebEMailExtrac.* [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebFetch [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebGo\ IS [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebHook [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebLeacher [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebMiner [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebMirror [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebReaper [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebSauger [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ eXtractor [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Website\ Quester [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Webster [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebStripper [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} WebWhacker [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WebZIP [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Wget [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Whacker [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Widow [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^WWWOFFLE [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^x-Tractor [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xaldon\ WebSpider [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Xenu [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus.*Webster [OR]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^Zeus
   RewriteRule ^.* – [F,L]
   ```