# How to disable right click in my HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to use the below script to disable right-click on my `HTML` page. 

But I'm getting

> Unexpected identifier error.

```
<script language="javascript">
    document.onmousedown=disableclick;
    status="Right Click Disabled";
    Function disableclick(e){
        if(event.button==2){
            alert(status);
            return false;   
         }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `e.button` and not `event.button` as you are passing in `e`

Comment: `Function` != `function` and `e` != `event`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code in javascript,

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```

reference from [How do I disable right click on my web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page)

Working Snippet :

```js
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```

```html
<p>Right Click Disabled</p>
```