# How to test if contextmenu is open or displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, contextmenu

I have a page with a few `pre` tags in it containing computer code.  I have a `mouseover` event listener, which highlights all the code in the `pre` tag.  I also have it remove the highlighting on a `mouseout` event.  Works real well if you use the keyboard to copy (ctrl-C).

But if you want to right-click and copy from the context menu, there is a problem.  The moment the mouse enters the context menu, it triggers the `mouseout` event of the `pre` tag.

I need a way to test if the context menu is currently open or displayed.  Then I can cancel removing the highlighting.  Is there a way to test if the context menu is open or displayed?

I don't want anything jquery, please.

My final alternative to this problem might be the `oncontextmenu`, but I don't know how I would find out if it closes.  Unless I try an event listener for the `mouseout` event of the context menu, if posible.

Here's my code so far:

```
window.onload = function(){

    function selectText(element) {
        var range, selection;

        if(window.getSelection) {
            selection = window.getSelection();
            range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(element);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
    }

    function unSelectText() {
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }

    preTags = document.getElementsByTagName('PRE');

    for(var i = 0; i < preTags.length; i++) {
        preTags[i].onmouseover = function() {selectText(this)};
        preTags[i].onmouseout = function() {unSelectText(this)};
    }

    codeTags = document.getElementsByTagName('CODE');

    for(var i = 0; i < codeTags.length; i++) {
        codeTags[i].onmouseover = function() {selectText(this)};
        codeTags[i].onmouseout = function() {unSelectText(this)};
    }
};
```

Comment: I've tried your code, and for me, opening the context menu to copy the selected code DOES NOT remove the selection: https://jsfiddle.net/koldev/qsg2eLvc The click on the Copy menu item works, the auto-selected code is copied to the clipboard. Which browser do you use? -- Edit: the code works in Chrome 89 but the code is not copied in Firefox 81.

Comment: I think this problem in Firefox can only be solved if you stop the context menu from appearing (https://stackoverflow.com/a/737043/600135), and create your own context menu using HTML, CSS and JavaScript. There are many implementations on the web, for example: https://www.sitepoint.com/building-custom-right-click-context-menu-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no event in JS to trigger the closing action of the context menu box and no reliable workarround: so far as I know from different researches the answer to your question is no.

But there is a way to solve your problem with an custom context menu if you may think about a similar method.

**Short explanation**

1. Add a custom context menu to your `code` and `pre` elements. In your case there is only one item `copy` needed (in the example quick! and very! simplified! demonstrated as simple box).
2. When open the menu deactivate right click to avoid stopping the selection of your code (was your question/issue as I understand)
3. When open the menu deactivate right click on other elements so you don't have other context menus open
4. When click on menu item start copy action close and reset
5. When click outside menu close and reset

**SIMPLIFIED example**

Please notice: the example is a QUICK, DIRTY AND VERY SIMPLIFIED example to demonstrate the technique. I tsure needs to be adapted to your special project.

```js
window.onload = function(){

    // general vars
    let isOpenContextMenu = false;
    const $contextMenu = document.getElementById('contextMenu');
    // all code/pre elements in one object to use in one loop
    const $codeElements = document.querySelectorAll('pre, code');
    let $actualCodeElement = {};



    // methods
    function selectText(element) {
        var range, selection;

        if(window.getSelection) {
            selection = window.getSelection();
            range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(element);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
    }

    function unSelectText() {
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    }



    // listeners


    // block right clicke when context menu on code/pre element is open
    function listenerContextMenuBlocked(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();
    }


    // clicks when context menu on code/pre elements is open
    function listenerMenuClick(ev){ 

        let $clickedElement = ev.target;
        do{

            if($clickedElement == $contextMenu){

                // clicked on context menu

                // --> copy action
                let codeToCopy = $actualCodeElement.innerText;
                let temporaryInput = document.createElement('input');
                temporaryInput.type = 'text';
                temporaryInput.value = codeToCopy;
                document.body.appendChild(temporaryInput);
                temporaryInput.select();
                document.execCommand('Copy');
                document.body.removeChild(temporaryInput);

                // --> close menu and reset
                $contextMenu.classList.remove('contextMenu--active');
                isOpenContextMenu = false;
                window.removeEventListener('contextmenu', listenerContextMenuBlocked);
                return;
            }
            $clickedElement = $clickedElement.parentNode;

        } while($clickedElement)


        // clicked outside context menu
        // --> close and reset
        $contextMenu.classList.remove('contextMenu--active');
        isOpenContextMenu = false;
        window.removeEventListener('contextmenu', listenerContextMenuBlocked);

    }


    // open custom context menu when right click on code/pre elements
    function listenerOpenContextMenuCodeBlock(e) {

        e.preventDefault();
    
        // used to copy conten in listenerMenuClick() 
        $actualCodeElement = e.target;
            
        if(false === isOpenContextMenu){
            
            // open context menu
            $contextMenu.style.top = e.clientY + 2 + 'px';
            $contextMenu.style.left = e.clientX + + 2 + 'px';
            $contextMenu.classList.add('contextMenu--active');
            
            isOpenContextMenu = true;
            window.addEventListener('click', listenerMenuClick);
            window.addEventListener('contextmenu', listenerContextMenuBlocked);

        }

    }



    for(var i = 0; i < $codeElements.length; i++) {

        //$actualElement = $codeElements[i];  // 
        $codeElements[i].addEventListener('contextmenu', listenerOpenContextMenuCodeBlock);
        $codeElements[i].onmouseover = function() {
            if(false === isOpenContextMenu){
                selectText(this)
            }
        };
        $codeElements[i].onmouseout = function() {
            if(false === isOpenContextMenu){
                unSelectText(this)
            }
        };
    }

};
```

```css
/* styles needed for custom context menu */
html {
    position: relative;

}
#contextMenu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 12px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    border: 1px solid #a5a5a5;
    box-shadow: 2px 3px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);;
    cursor: context-menu; 
    z-index: 10;
}

#contextMenu:hover {
    background-color: #aad7f3;
}
#contextMenu.contextMenu--active {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- SIMPLIFIED custom context menu for code/pre elements = hidden on page -->
<nav id="contextMenu" style="top: 50px; left: 30px" >
    <div>Copy Codeblock</div>
</nav>


<!-- example elements for code presentation / testing -->
<pre>
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
    Provident magni blanditiis, ea necessitatibus esse nihil, 
    quae iste explicabo beatae perspiciatis quibusdam tempora minima, 
    eos molestias illum voluptatum voluptate ipsum perferendis!
</pre>

<code>
    Li Europan lingues es membres del sam familie. Lor separat existentie 
    es un myth. Por scientie, musica, sport etc, litot Europa usa li sam vocabular. 
    Li lingues differe solmen in li grammatica, li pronunciation e li plu commun vocabules. 
    Omnicos directe al desirabilite de un nov lingua franca: On refusa continuar payar 
    custosi traductores. 
</code>
```

Comment: So far this seems to be the way to go.  But I'm curious if it's possible to skip the menu all together and trigger a copy off the right-click?

Comment: I am not quite sure if I got it right. Do you mean on right click not opening a custom context menu but just initiate the copy action immediatly and showing a message  'Element has been copied to clipboard'? Could be a way too. In that case it's a question about the user experience I think. It is an unexpected occurence ... nut maybe if you show a message 'copy element on right click when hovering the element ... could be a solution to. At first glance it is a similar code mechanic so the example could be adapted to that.

Comment: Yes, right-click copy, no menu appears at all, not even status mesage.  It is assumed that copy occured.  Highlighting can turn off after copy.  User experience is not important as it is just me.  Anybody else using this will just have to learn for themselves!

Comment: Ah ... a rough and dirty code snippet or whatever collection to reuse I asume 'g ... OK. No user UI ... but to be honest: for myself I would add at minimum a response that copy has been done. Working withou that feedback would kidding me ... and it's fun to add such functions to own coding tools ;-)

Comment: Ok, I tested your code, and two problems.  First, it doesn't seem to copy in SeaMonkey (Mozilla).  And second, when I do 'alerts' to watch the creation of the temporaryInput, I notice it removes all the newlines.  The original question has become very convoluted, I think I need to create a new question.  You gave the most hope for what I want, so take the bounty. Ty.

Comment: Seemonkey ... holla ... a rar request ... Did you have have a look to the used browser engine (version), did they change to the actual engine yet? I couldn't figure it out by a quick view. It could be that that is not up to date but that is just guesswork. On copying: you need to have a look to the block with copy action. Actual it uses the `innerText` property to copy the actual element. Just the simple standards to demonstrate. Maybe you like to try `innerHtml`. Indeed you need to adapt the code to your needs ... Thx 4 the bounty. Really great :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not really an answer to your specific question, but from a UX point of view, selecting text on hover can be confusing. The user might think it's just a hover effect. It's probably better to just have a "copy" button next to the text or to click the text to copy. That comes with the added benefit that the user only needs to click once.

```js
document.getElementById("code").addEventListener("click", function () {
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(this.innerText);
});
```

```css
#code {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<pre id="code">
print("hello, world")
print("hello, world")
print("hello, world")
</pre>
<p>Click to copy.</p>
```

Comment: "this is not really an answer to your specific question".

Comment: Just as nice notice: Well. Maybe it is not the concret way you asked for and as this it not must be bountied. But we are here for solutions and suggestions. This is a suggestion to think forward. And i think it could be worth to think about that if UX is a subject in the/a project. A reason why not the chosen answer. But maybe not a reason to vote down ...