# Hide API response in Inspect Element Network tab

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am working on an Angular application login page. The **API response** for Login API contains some **sensitive information** in the response that can be **traced** on the network tab.

Is there any way to **hide** the API response in the network tab? or any other solution?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to disable the right-click on the window.

add `oncontextmenu="return false;"` on your body or element.

[How do I disable right click on my web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page)