# Can I disable right click on website messenger chat option?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, web

Can I disable right click on my web page messenger chat option? I ask this because most browsers allow user to disable JavaScript but if i right-click messenger it shows the inspect option with view page source.

Comment: Can you? Probably. Should you? No, absolutely not. There are lots of ways to open devtools besides right clicking the DOM. Any effort you spend trying to disable the right click action will be a complete waste that would be better spent improving security on the server side, if that's your concern here.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks For your response, I Liked what you have suggested, Might Try it Thanks a Lot

Comment: Here is the answere you're looking for
https://stackoverflow.com/a/737043/5398327