# How can I protect my html website from being copied by http web copier?

Tags: html, http, web

I have a website made of HTML, CSS, js. How can I protect my web from being copied by http web copier?

So that no one can see the inner HTML.

Comment: You cannot do this. All the html css and javascript shown to users will be visible to them when they right click and press view page source. Howerver you can disable right click ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page)

Comment: @ShlokJain you could still do the same thing by pressing F12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant, the html/css/js and all the resources the front-end uses will be available for anyone to copy (and edit) as the browser need them and they have to be visible, and as the browser can see it, the developer tools of the browser can too, therefore, it can be copied.

There are some frameworks that compile your code before "sending" it to the browser so it recieves raw html/css etc that may be different from what you actually have coded, and also send them without formatting on purpose so its harder to read by a human, this can be done for security reasons.

But if you are worried about someone copying your work you should use a License

Answer (score -1):

You can't.

It's completely impossible.  You cannot send something to someone and expect them not to receive it.