# Using CSS and Javascript how to enable the scroll bar even if used pointer-events:none; css property

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, right-click

I am trying to disable the right-click on content. For that, I used the `"pointer-events: none;"` CSS property. But using that CSS property I am not able to scroll to see the complete content.
If I use the `"pointer-events: none;"` property how do enable the scroll bar or For disable the right click instead of using the `"pointer-events: none;"` CSS property is there any other option we have.

Please find my sample code below. Please Any help appreciated.

[Sample Application](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GRTSGAH1NVAJ)  - Using this link you can check the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<iframe src="https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#toolbar=0" 
  style="pointer-events:none;" 
  title="Iframe Example"></iframe>

<script>

</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable right click on my web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page)

Comment: @decpk yes. I tried that code but not working which I expected.

Comment: Since iframe has it's own window/document, you'd have to do it from within iframe page itself, can't do it from the parent page

Comment: Is your parent domain is same as in iframe...? If both are same you can expose a method in iframe window object and invoke it from parent window on your desired event