# Disable Right Click on WordPress Site

Tags: php, html, wordpress, code-snippets

I wanted to disable right click on my wordpress site. I have written a small snippet and inserted into body which disables right click, CTRL events and keyups.

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false" onselectstart="return false" onkeydown="if ((arguments[0] || window.event).ctrlKey) return false"></body>
```

but it is annoying when I want to copy something on site. is there a way I can modify the current snippet like only logged in users would be able to access the disabled events?

Cheers.

Comment: check this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page

Comment: Well, I get it @RonvanderHeijden The point is stealing contents. I want to disable CTRL + Copy and right click. a person with a basic knowledge wouldn't know to view source with shortcuts.

Comment: when the client requires it to be that way, you do it that way. :/ I know, as a SE, I get it.

Comment: I am not clear of your point. what factors could affect UX in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I have created a JS page in the directory named: "preventcopy.js" and added restricted the events using below JS

```
document.oncontextmenu = function() {
  return false
};
document.onselectstart = function() {
  if (event.srcElement.type != "text" && event.srcElement.type != "textarea" && event.srcElement.type != "password") return false;
    else return true;
  };
  if (window.sidebar) {
    document.onmousedown = function(e) {
      var obj = e.target;
      if (obj.tagName.toUpperCase() == "INPUT" || obj.tagName.toUpperCase() == "TEXTAREA" || obj.tagName.toUpperCase() == "PASSWORD") return true;
     else return false;
  }
};
if (parent.frames.length > 0) top.location.replace(document.location);
```

and then in function.php I enabled access for logged in users as below.

```
function copyrightpro_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'copyrightpro', get_template_directory_uri() . '/copyprevent.js', array(), false );
}
if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'copyrightpro_scripts' );
}
```

That's how it is been accomplished. But I would highly suggest enabling these features for users considering the user experience.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using existing wordpress plugin?

for example [using this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-right-click-for-wp/)

This plugin is used to disable right click on website to prevent cut, copy, paste, save image, view source, inspect element etc.

But when Administrator or Site Editor is logged in, he can access everything without any of the above restrictions.

Comment: Plugin recommendations are considered off-topic on this site.

Comment: Thanks, I would try my best not to use plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply put a conditional inside the body tag. You would want this in your theme's header.php file.  You also want the wordpress function `body_class` to include all of the other classes that should appear in the body tag.

```php
<body <?php if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'oncontextmenu="return false" onselectstart="return false" onkeydown="if ((arguments[0] || window.event).ctrlKey) return false"';
} ?> <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Comment: Unfortunately Howard, it doesn't seem like working. Injected in header.php. and I am not cleat of include all of the other classes.

Comment: You need to find where the body is declared in your theme.

Comment: I injected through the elementor custom code.

Comment: How did you do this? Explain it like I don't know what this elementir custom code thing is. Please add to your question if it's relevant.  I would say that I also agree with the other comments that disabling the right click is pointless.

Comment: disabling right click is pointless, I understood. for some reason, its required to add the snippet for disabling highlighting contents and copy paste or view its source. The snippet you shared, I inserted in elementor custom codes body start instead of my theme's body. My theme files are kinda complicated.

Comment: The `body` tag is definitely somewhere in your theme (most likely in header.php).  You can't just drop another `<body>` tag into the page.

Answer (score 0):

Just disable context menu not select or other events.

```
<body <?php if(!is_user_logged_in()) { echo 'oncontextmenu="return false"'; }?>></body>
```

Comment: Please read the question. The logged in users can be able to right click or copy contents when others shouldn't.