# Enable right click on texteditor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this code in my index.html file, to prevent using right-click except on editing fields:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(data){
       $(document).bind('contextmenu',function(e){
        var t = $(e.target).closest('#editor,.validatebox-text');   // enable right click on HTML editor and all input's
        if (!t.length){
          e.preventDefault();           
        }
      });      
    });
  </script>
```

question is - how to enable right-click on texteditor, too?
Thank you

Comment: Do you mean a `<textarea>`?

Comment: try with passing tags which you want to enable right click in `closet()` function instead of passing id and class name

Answer (score 0):

I tried with :

```
var t = $(e.target).closest('#editor,.validatebox-text,textarea');
```

[Disclaimer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/737043/16688813)

Answer (score 0):

Adding tags to the `closest()` function should enable right click on them.

```
var t = $(e.target).closest('input, textarea');
```