# Disable Copy, Cut, Paste and Right Click for PDF inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

I can't disable Copy, Cut, Paste and Right Click actions for PDF inside iframe

my code for the iframe

```
<iframe id="pdfViewer" src="url-pdf.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0" title="Title PDF" frameborder="0" scrolling="auto"  class="no-right-click no-cut-copy-paste" height="400px" width="100%" style="border: 30px solid #EEE"></iframe>
```

I've tried many solutions, but no one is work for me

Some solution I've tried using

**1. css**:

```
.no-cut-copy-paste {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

**2. Javascript**

```
var pdfViewer = document.getElementById('pdfViewer');
pdfViewer.window.eval('document.addEventListener("contextmenu", function (e) {e.preventDefault();}, false)');

$(document).on('cut copy paste', '.no-cut-copy-paste',  function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

**3. jQuery**

```
$('#pdfViewer').attr('contextmenu', 'return false')
```

But there is work for all pages of my application, but the right click is still active on iframe

```
document.oncontextmenu = function() { 
    return false; 
};
```

Comment: What is the use case? You do know that if I SEE your PDF, it is MINE to do what I want?

Comment: You can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page

Answer (score -1):

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Disable Context Menu</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/jscript">
    function injectJS(){    
        var frame =  $('iframe');
        var contents =  frame.contents();
        var body = contents.find('body').attr("oncontextmenu", "return false");
        var body = contents.find('body').append('<div>New Div</div>');    
    }
</script>

</head>
<body >

<iframe id="myiframe" width="528" height="473"  onload="injectJS()"
></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```