# Disabling right click brave browser

Tags: html, right-click, brave

I am trying to disable right click on my website. I tried with:

```
<body oncontextmenu="return false">
```

But it doesn't work in Brave browsers, in other browsers it look to work. Does anyone know why, and how can I disabling right click in all browser?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable right click on my web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page)

Answer (score 0):

This question will solve your problem, [How do I disable right click on my web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page).

I tested it in Brave with this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/dnuLcoh7/

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```

Comment: it doesn't work for me in brave. I use 1.42.97 version.

Comment: @miel I just tested the jsfiddle in 1.42.97 and it works for me. I tested on MacOS with  a trackpad and Windows with a mouse. You will need to provide more clear code examples and descriptions of what you're doing for us to help you.