# Disable Right Click and Control+u

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating an application and I need to disable the right mouse click and the control +u of the whole application.

How can I make a component to disable control+u and right mouse button in every application?

Comment: Not sure what your end goal is here. Anyone can always append `view-source:` in front of the URL in order to see the source and there is no way to disable that remotely

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I disable right click on my web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737022/how-do-i-disable-right-click-on-my-web-page)